# Using RxJava in android database managment

Tags: android, rx-java

I've just started to grasp RxJava and want to implement new API in my project with it.

Currently the brief workflow of the app is pretty common:
`Dispatch event and start the corresponding Loader` -> `handle response in OnError/OnSucces callbacks` -> `save data in Database` -> `post event with EventBus` -> `read from the Database`

It is clear how we implement the same with Rx except one thing - how the database should be managed?

I know Jake Wharton [is working](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2nzk7n/rxjava_for_sqlite/) on his Observable DB, but are there any practices to use the existing DB with RxJava?

Comment: Couchbase has an RxJava api. Appreciate it's nosql but worth taking a look and seeing if it meets your needs.

Comment: I have an observable query implementation for JDBC-driven databases in https://github.com/akarnokd/akarnokd-tools-and-utils/blob/master/akarnokd-tools/src/hu/akarnokd/utils/database/DB.java .